# Calculadora en tiempo real - imprimir resultado sin input

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo una calculadora en tiempo real pero necesito que el resultado se imprima dentro de una etiqueta `<p>` o similar.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```js
document.getElementById("tb").addEventListener("input", function() {
    var precio2;
    var cantidad2;
    var total2;
    precio2 = document.getElementById('precio1').value;
    cantidad2 = document.getElementById('cantidad').value;
    total2 = precio2 * cantidad2;
    document.getElementById('total1').value = total2;
});
```

```html
<input type="number" class="form-control mb-2" name="cantidad" id="cantidad" placeholder="C/Personas" min="1" max="{{$invitation->cantidad}}" required>
<input type='hidden' name='precio1' id='precio1' value='{{$invitation->dias->c_entrada}}' style='color: black; background: transparent; border: 0; text-align: center;' readonly>

<!-- AQUI ME GUSTARIA IMPRIMIR EL RESULTADO DE LA MULTIPLICACION -->
<div class="text-center"> Total: $  <div name="total1" id="total1"></div> </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estabas muy cerca de lograrlo, el `id = tb` no existe en tu codigo, ademas para cambiar el texto de un `div` necesitas usar `innerHTML`.  Quedaria asi:

```js
document.getElementById("cantidad").addEventListener("input",function() {
  var precio2;
  var cantidad2;
  var total2;
  precio2 = document.getElementById('precio1').value;
  cantidad2 = document.getElementById('cantidad').value;
  total2 = precio2 * cantidad2;
  document.getElementById('total1').innerHTML = total2;

});
```

```html
<input type="number"   class="form-control mb-2" name="cantidad" id="cantidad" placeholder="C/Personas" min="1" max="{{$invitation->cantidad}}" required>

<input type='hidden' name='precio1' id='precio1' value='5' style='color: black; background: transparent; border: 0; text-align: center;' readonly>


// AQUI ME GUSTARIA IMPRIMIR EL RESULTADO DE LA MULTIPLICACION
<div class="text-center"> Total: $  <div name="total1" id="total1"></div> </div>
js:
```

Comment: Gracias, era .innerHTML lo que me faltaba